# KAFKA - Assign consumer group in existing topics

Tags: offset, apache-kafka

In our production environment we have more than 25 topics.

Recently we installed KafkaOffsetMonitor tool which is used to monitor kafka offset.
But the tools shows only 3 topics information and it not show 22 topics.
When we verified we found all 22 topics doesn't have consumer group.
If consumer group is there then only we can monitor.

Question is: How to assign consumer group for existing topics?

Comment: Take a look at [Why some of the consumers in a consumer group never receive any message?](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Whysomeoftheconsumersinaconsumergroupneverreceiveanymessage?) maybe it helps you.